# "Remember me" login functionality

Tags: forms, login, input-fields, cognitive-load, remember-me

Is there any research available about the viability and use of "Remember Me" toggles/check boxes on login flows? I can't seem to find any information on whether or not they're used or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "viability" in this case? Are you looking for how people trust such a feature, how often they use it, or something different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a super-informal hallway study about a week ago. So, obviously not something to cite, but may give you some ideas for your own study.

I asked 10 people if they found the 'remember me' feature useful in the context of a secure mobile app (context is likely key here).

7 out of 10 said they rarely use it namely because they forget to check it before they log in most of the time.

5 out of 10 said that when they need to remember a login, they use 3rd party password management software to handle it for them (like 1Password or the web browser itself).

My personal opinion: They don't hurt, but likely don't help as much as we think they do. I personally fall into that group of 7 in that I usually time in my credentials, hit submit, THEN see the 'remember me' checkbox too late.

Comment: _"They don't hurt, but likely don't help as much as we think they do."_ - That is a very good synopsis. I personally do not implement it on my websites, because people often use their web browers to remember their login credentials anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any paper written on this subject. Perhaps you could start by looking at the following websites:

http://usabilitypost.com/2009/10/05/remember-me

http://www.siteflex.com.au/blog/n/remember-me-remember-me-not-140407

http://www.foresee.com/usability-perspective-5-financial-services-login-tips-better-customer-experience/

[Remember Me in an enterprise application: What to remember?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/44294/remember-me-in-an-enterprise-application-what-to-remember)

[Do we really need a "Remember me" option on a Login page?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22216/do-we-really-need-a-remember-me-option-on-a-login-page)

http://www.sitepoint.com/3-rules-painless-account-ux-login-screens/

Good luck,
Antonio

Comment: Thanks. May consider that this answer would be more useful if it included a meta-analysis of the links provided.